# Flutter/Dart - Null Check Error with data provided by PageViewBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-pageview, null-check

I'm getting the following nullcheck errors on data provided by a `PageViewBuilder`;

```
The following _CastError was thrown building:
Null check operator used on a null value

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _StageBuilderState.createViewItem (package:speakoholic/screens/mainStage.dart:488:161)
#1      _StageBuilderState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:speakoholic/screens/mainStage.dart:138:18)
```

Line 488 is `speakcraft.tagname!` when calling this function;

```
child: editIcon(
       context: context, 
       userid:speakcraft.userid!, 
       audioid:speakcraft.audioid!, 
       title: speakcraft.title!, 
       tagname:speakcraft.tagname!),
```

And line 138 is the `createViewItem`

```
   PageView.builder(
    itemCount: widget.speakcrafts.length,        
    itemBuilder: (context, int currentIndex) {
      return createViewItem(widget.speakcrafts[currentIndex], context, currentIndex, widget.speakcrafts.length );
    },       
  );
```

Heres' the function;

```
Widget editIcon({
  required BuildContext? context, 
  required int? userid, 
  required int? audioid, 
  required String? title, 
  required String? tagname}) {
  return
    FutureBuilder<int?>(                       
        ///some stuff
    );
}
```

How do I resolve these nullcheck errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use a non-nullable value with using a `Bang !` operator (also known as null-assertion operator) to cast away nullability: `tagname:speakcraft.tagname!`.

On the other hand, your property is nullable as `String? tagname` means that `tagname` can be `null`.

So, in order to avoid this you can change your `editIcon` method:

```
editIcon(
   ...
   tagname:speakcraft?.tagname ?? 'some default value'),
```